# Which string would break first?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string

Two equal masses ($m_1,m_2$) are attached by a string as shown. The string is then spun in a vertical circle, with the center being the open end of the string attached to $m_1$. Which string would break first if the strings could handle a maximum amount of tension?

[image]

Comment: Your description is a bit difficult to visualize. Would you mind rephrasing, or adding a diagram?

Comment: Is that the double pendulum? And If the plane of the circle is the vertical, it should firstly obey some laws to ensure we'll always see a double pendulum, not projectiles.

Comment: This question shows no effort to solve the problem, and is not asking about a conceptual difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how long the strings are, how heavy the masses are, and other things not specified in the original question, but assuming:

- Both strings are the same length
- Both masses are the same length
- Both strings are the same thickness and made from the same material 
  and
- By a "vertical circle" you mean a circle within a single horizontal plane (for instance, around your head).

Then I think the inner string would break first.  Here's my reasoning...

The outer mass B is twice as far from the center as the inner mass A, therefore it has to accelerate twice as fast to keep up the same rotational speed.  This implies that the net centripetal force on mass B pulling toward the center has to be twice as much as the net centripetal force pulling mass A toward the center.  Let's denote these two forces by F and 2F.

Because every action causes an equal and opposite reaction, the inward force of 2F the outer string exerts on mass B has to be equal to the tension of the outer string which is equal to the outward force it exerts on mass A.  In other wards, the outer string pulls B inward with a force of 2F, and A outward with a force of 2F.  But since the net force on A has to be just F in the inward direction rather than 2F in the outward direction, this implies that the inward force on A due to the inner string has to be 3F.  Which in turn means that the tension in the inner string, as well as the force of it pulling your hand is also 3F.  In other wards, the tension in the inner string is 1.5 times as much as the tension in the outer string so it should break first.

Comment: No calculations? It's an analytic problem.

Comment: I calculated the ratio of 1.5 by dividing 3F by 2F.  If you want me to write it out more explicitly, the calculation is 3F/2F = 1.5.  ie, the tension on the inner string is 50% more than the outer string.

Comment: What  you said is not general. If I have understood the configuration, There is no need for both of masses and the pivot to be along one line. That may cause problems. And gravity! it changes the plane of motion from horizontal. In fact if there is gravity, there is no way that we achieve a horizontal motion plane.

Comment: Centrifugal force pulls both masses outward as you swing it around in a circle.  Nothing pulls them in any other direction.  I disagree that gravity is relevant, unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming from your diagram that there is a piece of string from $m_1$ to $m_2$, and another piece of string connected just to $m_1$, which is held to swing the two masses in a circle.

Imagine there are two separate strings - one attached to $m_1$ and the other to $m_2$. When you swing both around in a circle at the same time, there will be some tension in each string ($T_1$ and $T_2$ respectively).

Now tie the ends of the two pieces of string together, and attach a third piece of string there. Swinging both of them by that one string, you now have to provide the full force (tension) for moving both $m_1$ and $m_2$ in a circle. Clearly, this new tension is $T_1 + T_2$.

If the string is equally strong at all points, it will break where the tension is greatest.

Can you figure it out now?